# rewrite subdomain to direcory in same server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I have a domain, lets say **mydomain.com**.

I want every subdomain of this to load the contents of the directory with the same name... For example, if someone writes

http://sub.mydomain.com/index.php

I want to show him the contents of

http://sub.mydomain.com/sub/index.php

Still, I want it to show in the addressbar the http://sub.mydomain.com/index.php

The apache vhost is like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName *.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/subs/www
  ... more stuff ...
</VirtualHost>
```

so in the filesystem, the files for the example above would be under the directory

/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/subs/www/sub

I tried many of the proposed solutions here, but most of them were redirects to some other domain/subdomain or end up in a redirect loop :(

tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some rewrite rules that will examine the sub domain and then rewrite to the relevant path:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias *.mydomain.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.mydomain\.com
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /%1/$1

  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/subs/www

  ... more stuff ...

</VirtualHost>
```

What this will do is capture anything preceding ".mydomain.com" then rewrite it into the URL as %1, $1 will be the requested resource such as index.html

Be aware this might trip you up if www.mydomain.com is a valid domain for your site!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! 

It is correct, you saved me a lot of time, but I cannot accept it until you edit your post and change the 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).\mydomain\.com
to 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.mydomain\.com
(small typo in escaping the dot)

Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: Good spot! Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^sub(|/$) /sub%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you!The thing is that i want EVERY subdomain to do such an internal redirection, not only the "sub" subdomain (as pointed out in my question)